# Discord.py - Guild.categories return empty list

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot and I need to get the guild categories list, so I can create a new channel under a specific category that already has the permissions I want.

This is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    group = await client.fetch_guild('Guild ID')
    categories_list = group.categories
    # print so I can see the categories_list
    print(categories_list)
    
    # more stuff...
```

This is the result:

[ ]

Comment: Welcome to stack Tarik! Have you tried removing the quotation marks around Guild ID? In the current versions, `fetch_guild` takes an integer, not a string.

Comment: that would result in an attributeerror, it’s returning an empty list.

Comment: the problem is that fetch_guild doesn’t return the channels/members/categories, use get_guild instead

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszKwieciński the get_guild method worked!